# How to iterate through multiple sets of data and input data into a method repeatedly? (tkinter, selenium, python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, tkinter, automation, webautomation

I am trying to write an automation program that will take user inputed data from a singular UI and auto-input that data into a single website or multiple websites.

[image: UI]

When the "Get Quote" button is pressed, a chrome browser session opens and places all the data from the UI into its corresponding entry fields within the website.

[image: browsersessionexample]

What I am trying to figure out now is how to account for situations when there is more than 1 sets of data. For example:

[image: UIexample2]

Here is a picture of what I want the program to be able to do. Basically input the second set of data and click "Add line Item" and if there isn't any data left to enter, then the script will automatically click "Generate Smart Quote."

[image: websessionexamplescenario]

What is the best approach to being able to input second or third sets of data? The data has to be re-inputted in the same method. Here is some code for context.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 

orders = {}
def order_data():
    # start by adding a dict to the dict with key of length dict,
    # the first key will be 0, then 1, 2 and so on
    orders[len(orders)] = {}

    # next you can start adding data using len - 1 to access the correct key
    # and so on for all your data
    orders[len(orders) - 1]['handling unit'] = e3.get()
    orders[len(orders) - 1]['pieces'] = e4.get()
    orders[len(orders) - 1]['description'] = e5.get()
    orders[len(orders) - 1]['length'] = e6.get()
    orders[len(orders) - 1]['width'] = e7.get()
    orders[len(orders) - 1]['height'] = e8.get()
    orders[len(orders) - 1]['weight'] = e9.get()
    orders[len(orders) - 1]['classification'] = e10.get()    


def GetQuote():

    origin_zip = int(e1.get()) #gets entries stores data here
    destination_zip = int(e2.get())
    handling_unit = [e3.get()]
    pieces = [e4.get()]
    description = [e5.get()]
    length = [e6.get()]
    width = [e7.get()]
    height = [e8.get()]
    weight = [e9.get()]
    classification_list =[e10.get]

    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/***/***/chromedriver")

    driver.maximize_window() #driver.set_window_size(10, 10)

    #1st Tab (shipco.com)
    driver.get("https://tms.shipco.com/Main/Home")
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)

    #1st Tab Login Page
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='dropdownMenuButton']").click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='UserName']").send_keys('***')
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='Password']").send_keys('***')
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block']").click()

    #1st Tab 2nd Page
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='OriginZip']").send_keys(origin_zip)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='DestinationZip']").send_keys(destination_zip)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-secondary form-control']").click()

    #Will have to add a conditional statement here to iterate through instances of multiple items/dimensions/weights

    #1st Tab 3rd Page
    driver.refresh();
    for i in range(len(orders)):
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "handlingunits").send_keys(orders[i]['handling unit'])
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "quantityofgoods").send_keys(orders[i]['pieces'])
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "commoditydescription").send_keys(orders[i]['description'])
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "sizelength").send_keys(orders[i]['length'])
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "sizewidth").send_keys(orders[i]['width'])
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "sizeheight").send_keys(orders[i]['height'])
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "totalweight").send_keys(orders[i]['weight'])

        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='ng-binding']").click()      #this will click the object that gets class for shipment
        if i < len(orders):
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-info']").click() 

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Generate Smart Quote')]").click()     

def insert_into_textbox(): #generates input fields for the next set of items

    order_data()   
    #get the inputs
    handling_unit = e3.get()
    pieces = e4.get()
    description = e5.get()
    length = e6.get()
    width = e7.get()
    height = e8.get()
    weight = e9.get()
    classification = e10.get()

    textbox_display = (handling_unit.ljust(11)+pieces.ljust(13)+description.ljust(11)+length.ljust(10)+width.ljust(11)+height.ljust(11)+weight.ljust(10)+classification+"\n")

    textbox.insert("end",textbox_display)
    e3.delete(0, "end")
    e4.delete(0, "end")
    e5.delete(0, "end")
    e6.delete(0, "end")
    e7.delete(0, "end")
    e8.delete(0, "end")
    e9.delete(0, "end")
    e10.delete(0, "end")


master = Tk() 
master.title("Quote Automator")
master.configure(background="#eef56e")
arial8 = font.Font(family="Arial", size=8, weight=font.BOLD)
algerian8 = font.Font(family="Algerian", size=8, weight=font.BOLD)

e1 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #origin zip
e2 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #destination zip
e3 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #handling unit(s)
e4 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #piece(s)
e5 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=13) #description(s)
e6 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #length(s)
e7 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #width(s)
e8 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #height(s)
e9 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #weight(s)
e10 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #class(s)

# grid method customizes position
e1.grid(row = 0, column = 2, pady = 1, sticky="W")  #origin zip
e2.grid(row = 0, column = 4, pady = 1, sticky="W") #destination zip
e3.grid(row = 3, column = 1, pady = 1, sticky="W") #handling unit(s)
e4.grid(row = 3, column = 2, pady = 1, sticky="W") #piece(s)
e5.grid(row = 3, column = 3, pady = 1, sticky="W")  #description(s)
e6.grid(row = 3, column = 4, pady = 1, sticky="W")  #length(s)
e7.grid(row = 3, column = 5, pady = 1, sticky="W") #width(s)
e8.grid(row = 3, column = 6, pady = 1, sticky="W") #height(s)
e9.grid(row = 3, column = 7, pady = 1, sticky="W") #weight(s)
e10.grid(row = 3, column = 8, pady = 1, sticky="W") #class(s)

textbox=Text(master, width=9, borderwidth=5, height=7)
textbox.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=9, sticky="nsew")

scrollbar=Scrollbar(master, orient="vertical", command=textbox.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=5, column=10, sticky=NS)
textbox.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)


b0 = Button(master, text = "Add Set", bg="white", fg="black", font=arial8, command=insert_into_textbox) #Add Next Set Button
b1 = Button(master, text = "Caculate Class", bg="yellow", font=arial8, command=set_class)
b2 = Button(master, text = "Get Quote", bg="#6fff00", fg="#7170ff", font=arial8, width=10, command=GetQuote) 

b0.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W) # Add Next Set Button Positioning
b1.grid(row = 0, column = 8, sticky = E) # Calculate Class Button Positioning
b2.grid(row = 0, column = 7, sticky = E) # Get Quote Button Positioning

mainloop()
```

[image: pic5]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like add each line to a dictionary, with each key being a number. Then each value could be another dictionary or a named tuple. Then you can loop through the number keys in your method to get the values for each line.

For example using a dict you can make a function to take in the data.

```
orders = {}
    def order_data():
        # start by adding a dict to the dict with key of length dict,
        # the first key will be 0, then 1, 2 and so on
        orders[len(orders)] = {}

        # next you can start adding data using len - 1 to access the correct key
        orders[len(orders) - 1]['handling unit'] = e3.get()
        # and so on for all your data
```

Then when you call your method you can use a for loop to input the data for each line.

```
for i in range(len(orders)):
    class.method(i)
```

Then inside your method for each send_keys function you can call the dictionary

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "handlingunits").send_keys(orders[i]['handling unit'])
```

You could also do the for loop inside the method if you prefer.

```
for i in range(len(orders)):
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "handlingunits").send_keys(orders[i]['handling unit'])
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "quantityofgoods").send_keys(orders[i]['pieces'])
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "commoditydescription").send_keys(orders[i]['description'])
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "sizelength").send_keys(orders[i]['length'])
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "sizewidth").send_keys(orders[i]['width'])
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "sizeheight").send_keys(orders[i]['height'])
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "totalweight").send_keys(orders[i]['weight'])

        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='ng-binding']").click()      #this will click the object that gets class for shipment
        if i < len(orders):
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-info']").click() #add another line of items if avaiable
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Generate Smart Quote')]").click()
```

Putting the 'add new line' part inside the loop with logic like this will make the program keep adding until data is expended and then it will click the 'Generate Smart Quote' button.

Comment: I implemented your code suggestions. The program runs but does not input the data in the entry fields within the web browser.

Comment: Have you bound the order_data function to a button? I can't see that in your code. I should have been more clear there, sorry. Also you need to put the code to add a new line within your loop

Comment: You can call the order_data function in your insert_into_textbox function and then the data should be entered into the dictionary

Comment: I added the order_data() to run from within the insert_into_textbox function. When I add a 2nd set of data, the data for each category is combined as shown in picture #6. 

What is a way to make it so the program will automatically click "add line item" when there is multiple sets of data and when all data is entered, click "Generate Smart Quote"?

Comment: So you need to put the line of code which clicks 'add line item' within the loop that adds the data, with some logic so it doesn't make another line after the last entry.
I will show an example in my answer.

Comment: I add your suggestions, the functionality to add multiple sets of data works. However, the program will not click the generate quote button. What can be added to break out of the loop and click the generate quote button?

Comment: When all the dictionary data has been used up the program should automatically break out of the loop and go on to the next command. I would double check your code to press the generate quote button, and make sure the code to press the quote button is outside of the loop.

Comment: I updated the code, the script is functioning as intended. Thank you so much for your help!